# Sticky jquery selected option

Tags: jquery

I have a page that shows users info like address, phone, name, etc., but the phone field is a select option where I can choose between (Phone,
For each user I have a select option:

```
<select class="smpullinput" id="middle_column_type<? echo $idtable; ?>">
    <option id="Phone" value="Phone">Phone</option>
    <option id="Office" value="Office">Office</option>
    <option id="Cellphone" value="Cellphone">Cellphone</option>
</select> 
//$idtable its just an ID
```

And then I display the data using simple jquery:

```
var idtable = <?=$idtable?>;
$('#middle_column_type'+idtable).change(function() {

    if( $('#middle_column_type'+idtable).val()=="Phone" )
        {                            
          $("#disp_p"+idtable).html(varp).show();
        }

     if( $('#middle_column_type'+idtable).val()=="Office" )
        {
          $("#disp_o"+idtable).html(varo).show();
        }       

     if( $('#middle_column_type'+idtable).val()=="Cellphone" )
        {
          $("#disp_c"+idtable).html(varc).show();
        }               
});
```

And I use span to display the phones. What I want now is to have a "sticky" select option, that if I change the select box to Cellphone in any user the other users get the new option, I know that in order to do that I need to use my class="smpullinput" (in my case) I tried some stuff that did not work. Not sure if I was clear enough?

Thanks

Comment: Are `varp`, `varo` and `varc` declared variables?

Comment: They Are, at the top of the document.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `$(".smpullinput").not(this).val(this.value);`, demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BTheR/